# React Native User Input into API params

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Beginner at React Native here that would appreciate some help!

I have inputs on one page that allow users to enter data, which will be saved as states. How can I allow those states to be the parameters of an api call? I have tried react-navigation, but an error appears that says "this.props.navigation" is undefined. However, passing the state into text tags (this.props.navigation.state.params.term) successfully shows the user input data.

Please and thank you!

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQtH6.png)

PreferencePage (where input is):

```
<View>
<CardSection>
<Input 
    label="Food"
    value={this.state.term}
    onChangeText={term => this.setState({ term })}
 />
 </CardSection>
 </View> 

 <View style={{marginTop: 5, marginBottom: 5}}>

 <TouchableOpacity>
   <Button  //onPress={this.onButtonPress.bind(this)}  
     onPress= {() => this.props.navigation.navigate('SwipeFunction', 
     {term: this.state.term})}
     title="Start Swiping" />
 </TouchableOpacity> 

 </View>
```

SwipeFunction page (where api call is):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';
import SwipeCard from './SwipeCard';
import PreferencePage from './PreferencePage';

class SwipeFunction extends Component {

constructor(){
super(props)
}

state = { 
businesses: [], 
profileIndex: 0 
};

config = {
headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer 8PFnRjBdeczBvlqjph1bzECWVbJDj_p4wpjf1fHFinCrNBfw5bjhsRF60TpwjjEQoyEesUm8vjG8taEzjXxI1XIRNYiPm8akqUgjxk6gUaVGMnKvsic8zIy-XfeYWnYx'},
params: {
  term: this.props.navigation.state.params.term,    
}
};

componentWillMount() {
axios.get('https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search', config)
.then(response => this.setState({ businesses: response.data.businesses }));
```

Comment: Can you post the full error please?

Comment: @Colin Sorry, added!

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to suggest that `this.props.navigation` is undefined. Make sure that `navigation` is properly passed as a prop to `PreferencePage`.

Comment: Do you mean make sure that navigation is properly passed to SwipeFunction?